# why typescript can not verify return type by function with generic?

Tags: typescript

I want to verify the return type with generic.But the behavior like blow confuse me:

```
interface IT {
  name: string;
}

interface check<T>   {
  get(): Partial<T>;
};

// works
var g: check<IT> = {
    get() {
        return {
            name: 'sdsdf',
            error: 'asdad'
        }
    }
}

// error
var e: check<IT> = {
    get() {
        return {
            name: 123
        }
    }
}

// error
var f: check<IT> = {
    get() {
        return {
            error: 'asdad'
        }
    }
}
```

why when the return type is extended the generic type, it can pass type check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wonder to know why { name: '123', error: '123' } can also pass the type check.error has not been defined

This is becaose of asignability.

Please consider next example:

```js
interface IT {
  name: string;
}

interface check<T> {
  get(): Partial<T>;
};

var g: check<IT> = {
  get() {
    return {
      name: 'sdsdf',
      error: 'asdad'
    }
  }
}

interface IT2 {
  name: string,
  error: string
}

declare var a: IT
declare var b: IT2

a = b // ok

b = a // error
```

As you can see IT2 can be assigned to IT, but not vice versa.

But WHY???

This is how types work in TypeScript. Please see first example of the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#our-first-interface)

> The type checker checks the call to printLabel. The printLabel function has a single parameter that requires that the object passed in has a property called label of type string. Notice that our object actually has more properties than this, but the compiler only checks that at least the ones required are present and match the types required. There are some cases where TypeScript isn’t as lenient, which we’ll cover in a bit.

There is no `Exact` type in TypeScript, but there is an open [enter link description here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936)

Please keep in mind, that next code will fail:

```js
const bar = g.get().error // error
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using different types in your return than you defined in your interface.

```js
interface IT {
  name: string;
}

// this will work
var e: check<IT> = {
    get() {
        return {
            name: "123" // needs to be a string
        }
    }
}

// this will not work
var f: check<IT> = {
    get() {
        return {
            error: 'asdad' // "error" was not a field defined on your interface
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I wonder to know why `{ name: '123', error: '123' }` can also pass the type check.`error` has not been defined.